# directory security using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following structure of web site.

website

-- adminpanel

------ images

------ .htaccess

-- websiteone

-- websitetwo

I have place .htaccess inside adminpanel for authorized access of directory:

```
AuthName "protected"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
```

Inside websiteone and websitetow ,I have pages that uses the images and other stuff of folder adminpanel.

**Problems:**
I have browse to adminpanel, it ask for logon that is what I want but It also prompt for logon when I browse to websiteone or websitetwo where I want to avoid the logon. This might be due to access of images of the adminpanel directory.

Is there any another way so that I can apply logon credential to only adminpanel but not to the websiteone or websitetwo directory?

Comment: It would be better, in my humble opinion, to use an authentication system for your scripting language, instead of using `mod_auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it would be better to do this within PHP, as the Apache mod_auth setup has some significant security issues, but if you must do it this way, try this:

In each folder of the adminpanel folder where you need access without a password (eg. images), create an .htaccess file and add this:

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

This will tell Apache that all authentication has been satisfied and allow access from anywhere.

If you need/want to specify specific files, you can use the Files directive:

```
<Files image.jpg>
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Or you can do a set of files that match a pattern using FilesMatch (images, in this instance):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Those should be all you need to poke some holes in the mod_auth setup and allow anonymous access.